# Execute certain commands one after other two all set of servers simultaneously

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to execute command 1 and command 2 on 6 servers simultaneously and after that I need to run command 3 and command 4.

```
#!/bin/sh
#Instance details
Server1="<Server1>"
Server2="<Server2>"
Server3="<Server3>"
Server4="<Server4>"
Server5="<Server5>"
Server6="<Server6>"
ssh root@$Server1 "command1" &
ssh root@$Server1 "command2" &
ssh root@$Server2 "command1" &
ssh root@$Server2 "command2" &
ssh root@$Server3 "command1" &
ssh root@$Server3 "command2" &
ssh root@$Server4 "command1" &
ssh root@$Server4 "command2" &
ssh root@$Server5 "command1" &
ssh root@$Server5 "command2" &
ssh root@$Server6 "command1" &
ssh root@$Server6 "command2" &
wait
ssh root@$Server1 "command3" &
ssh root@$Server1 "command4" &
ssh root@$Server2 "command3" &
ssh root@$Server2 "command4" &
ssh root@$Server3 "command3" &
ssh root@$Server3 "command4" &
ssh root@$Server4 "command3" &
ssh root@$Server4 "command4" &
ssh root@$Server5 "command3" &
ssh root@$Server5 "command4" &
ssh root@$Server6 "command3" &
ssh root@$Server6 "command4" &
```

Is there any better way of doing it, as I have around 10 servers and 10 commands each.

Please help an easy and a robosut way.

Comment: Check gnu-parallel

Comment: or if you don't have/can't install gnu-parallel, use nested `for` loops. ie. `for cmd in cmd1 cmd2 ... ; do for srvr in srvr1 srvr2 ... ; do ssh "$srvr" "$cmd"; done & ; done` (or very close). Dbl-quote your vars!. Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I use [ClusterShell](https://github.com/cea-hpc/clustershell) or [pdsh](https://github.com/chaos/pdsh) they both work great and you can easily specify a node range, e.g. `clush -w Server[1-6] command1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
cmds=( 
    'command1; command2'
    'command3; command4'
)
servers=( Server1 Server2 Server3 Server4 Server5 Server6 )

for c in "${cmds[@]}"; do
    for s in "${servers[@]}"; do 
        ssh root@"$s" "$c" &
    done
    wait
done
```

Comment: [tag:tmux] is also nice for this: create N panes, each for a separate login. Then you can synchronize the panes so that whatever you type into one pane is also entered into all the others. Demo: https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/sync-tmux-panes/